# How can I use node/npm-modules in angular project?

Tags: angular, import, module

I want to use node and npm modules in my angular project (angular-electron-app).

For example I want to use the module 'dns' (node module) in angular to make a dns lookup after button click event.

This is the code how to use it with node.

```
const dns = require('dns');
dns.lookup('google.com', options, (err, addresses) =>{  

    if(err != null) 
        {
            console('DNS Error');
            console.log(err);
        }
    else
        {   
            console.log('IP-Adresse: ');
            console.log(addresses);
        }
});
```

Now I want to use this functionality directly in my component.ts file in angular and my browser/electron app. That means after button click event the dns lookup should fired.

My problem now is how to import node modules or generally modules from extern sources (npm modules) in my project.

I tried it with this code in my component.ts:

```
import * as lookDNS from 'dns-lookup';


dnsCheck(): void {
console.log('dns check');

lookDNS.lookup('www.google.de', function (err, address, family) {
 console.dir(err);
 });
```

}

but the problem is that the browser cannot run javascript with 'require'.

Thanks for help!

Comment: link to library ? as in one you are loading dns and in the other one dns-lookup

Comment: In principle you are doing nothing wrong, the problem is with the library itself as for me it complains that is missing dns library than I installed the dns library and now is complaining about missing "."

Comment: @AvramVirgil yes that's right. dns is the raw node module and dns-lookup contains the functionality or use the dns module. I didn't find a way to include or import the dns node module so I tried it with dns-lookup via npm install. The problem is  I did't find a solution to import nodejs based modules or other modules to angular to use it in my components with typescript.